# Angular, input field with a currency mask directive for money format on the fly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create an input mask for a EU money field using http://jquerypriceformat.com/

So far in my directive, the input shows correctly to the user with the mask applied, but I believe there's something wrong, because the POST values are being sent with weird formatting, totally different than what we see in the input field.

I include the priceformat.js

```
<script src="js/jquery.price_format.1.8.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" currency-input ng-model...>
```

And on angular:

```
app.directive('currencyInput', function() {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        element.priceFormat({
            prefix: '',
            centsSeparator: ',',
            thousandsSeparator: '.'
        });
      }
    };
});
```

My input shows the value with the mask correctly, but on POST data (called by angular) it's a different value, what am I missing?

input > 2.200,80   |   post > 22,0080

Thanks

Comment: please post Fiddle/Plunker for debug usage. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From your example I don't see that link returns something.

I would write directive something like:

```
.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;


            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });


            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {

          elem.priceFormat({
            prefix: '',
            centsSeparator: ',',
            thousandsSeparator: '.'
        });                

                return elem[0].value;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Demo 1 <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/741/)</kbd>

[image]

If you want on start fire the filter, use `$formatters`:

Now `link` is:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            var format = {
                    prefix: '',
                    centsSeparator: ',',
                    thousandsSeparator: ''
                };

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                elem.priceFormat(format);

                return elem[0].value;
            });

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                elem[0].value = ctrl.$modelValue * 100 ;
                elem.priceFormat(format);
                return elem[0].value;
            })
        }
```

Demo 2 <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/1218/)</kbd>

Comment: Just works! Thank you very much. The fiddle is perfect, gosh, what do you guys eat?

Comment: @MaximShoustin thanks for this. This has some problem. When the $scope.test has some value value e.g. 1000 and the thousandsSeparator is '' (empty) the input field still shows '1.000,00' when the page has been loaded. When typing to the input field it works. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: @MaximShoustin thanks! But did you notice that when your initial value is 10000 the input says 100,00. Shouldn't it say 10000,00 ?

Comment: @iiro just add `* 100` in formatters:  `elem[0].value = ctrl.$modelValue * 100 ;`

Comment: How would you get the unformatted value back from the model? If I run this code, the model value is also e.g. "€ 45,00"?

Comment: @DanielPlomp as you noticed the output value is a String, not numeric. So just use string replace.

Comment: There is some problem. For example if you open the second fiddle and delete the number "1" from "100,00" the result is "0,00"

Answer (score 18):

Push a `$parser` to the controller, and only update the value when it doesn't match the input using `$setViewValue()` and `$render()`.

```
app.directive('currencyInput', function() {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        return ctrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {

            ...

            if (result != inputValue) {
                controller.$setViewValue(res);
                controller.$render();
            }
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Here's a fiddle with the logic I used for my currency input directive: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dubilla/dj6mX/798/)

Comment: I used your method, but now price is not posting to controller

Comment: Weird behavior when you try to backspace a comma. The $parser is applying the filter again.

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't return the input into the model variable. Make sure to `return inputVal.replace(/\D/g,'');` right after the render block if you want the integer value

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but I believe this deserves another answer! I've been using the [ng-currency](https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency) module. It's absolutely fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

I like Dubilla's approach cause of its simplicity and elegance. I decided to add (with due credits) some features on top of it to make it quite close to real world use case.

I've using it on a github project to create some useful finance directives [github](https://github.com/QuantumInformation/AngularDirectives/blob/master/app/directives/MoneyInput.js).

Notable extra features:

1. It does some rigorous checking of the inputs to give a valid response.
2. It has some keyboard shortcuts to make entering large numbers quicker.
3. I show how to integrate it with bootstrap and ngmodel css updates.
4. As a bonus I outputed the form's ngmonel as JSON to help people see how the form validation works in real time

It also uses a POJO as the ngmodel:

```
function Money() {
    this.notional = 0;
    this.maxValue = 99999999999.9;
    this.maxValueString = "99,999,999,999.9";
    this.maxPrecision = 10;
}
```

you can use it with Bootstrap 3 like so:

```
<h1>Currency Formatting directive</h1>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form name="myForm">

            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.notional.$invalid && myForm.notional.$touched}">
                <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.money.notional  " money="money" money-input size="30" required
                       name="notional"
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Enter notional amount"/>

                      <p class="help-block error" ng-show="myForm.notional.$error.required && myForm.notional.$touched">Required</p>



            </div>

            <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" type="submit">SAVE</button>
        </form>
        <h2>Tips</h2>
        <ol>

            <li> Entering 'k' will multiply the amount by one thousand</li>
            <li> Entering 'm' will multiply the amount by one million</li>
            <li> Entering 'b' will multiply the amount by one billion</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Form debugger</p>
<pre>
               form = {{ myForm | json }}
    </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to handle this without jQuery using only an Angular directive. This example doesn't support decimals. It's easy to modify it to support that though, just change the `$filter` in the `toView()` function.

In my opinion this is a better approach to solve the same problem, as you can avoid loading in jQuery and the currency plugin mentioned by the author. Locale support for Euro should be supported by the use the `$locale` properties, but I've only tested this for use in USD.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('currencyMask', []);

  // Controller
  app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.amount = 100000;
  }]);

  // Directive
  app.directive('inputCurrency', ['$locale', '$filter', function($locale, $filter) {

    // For input validation
    var isValid = function(val) {
      return angular.isNumber(val) && !isNaN(val);
    };

    // Helper for creating RegExp's
    var toRegExp = function(val) {
      var escaped = val.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
      return new RegExp(escaped, 'g');
    };

    // Saved to your $scope/model
    var toModel = function(val) {

      // Locale currency support
      var decimal = toRegExp($locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP);
      var group = toRegExp($locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP);
      var currency = toRegExp($locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM);

      // Strip currency related characters from string
      val = val.replace(decimal, '').replace(group, '').replace(currency, '').trim();

      return parseInt(val, 10);
    };

    // Displayed in the input to users
    var toView = function(val) {
      return $filter('currency')(val, '$', 0);
    };

    // Link to DOM
    var link = function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ngModel) {
      $ngModel.$formatters.push(toView);
      $ngModel.$parsers.push(toModel);
      $ngModel.$validators.currency = isValid;

      $element.on('keyup', function() {
        $ngModel.$viewValue = toView($ngModel.$modelValue);
        $ngModel.$render();
      });
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: link
    };
  }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="currencyMask" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input input-currency ng-model="amount">
 <p><strong>Amount:</strong> {{ amount }}</p>
</div>
```