# Angularjs, mask currency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576202/angular-input-field-with-a-currency-mask-directive-for-money-format-on-the-fly?answertab=active#tab-top) thread, which is from great help, but there is a problem that i couldn't solve. When you initialize the value in the controller the value doesn't 'get' with the mask

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LkPRkiE9HVFhiPWi8gwD?p=streamer) a example.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a thread in the portuguese stackoverflow and they gave me the help. The important thing was that same function that was used to format the value when  happened some change has to be used when the value is 'put in the field'.

```
app.directive('format', ['$filter',
  function($filter) {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;


        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(a) {
          elem[0].value = ctrl.$modelValue
          elem.priceFormat({
            prefix: '',
            centsSeparator: ',',
            thousandsSeparator: '.'
          });
          return elem[0].value;
        });

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
          elem.priceFormat({
            prefix: '',
            centsSeparator: ',',
            thousandsSeparator: '.'
          });
          return elem[0].value;
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

- [thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2899/problema-em-mascara-de-moeda-em-input?answertab=active#tab-top) in the portuguese stackoverflow.
- [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nvhQ1cb74kns1didAaZ8?p=preview)