# How to Format Currency in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want to try to format currency in an input using Angular. I tried doing this:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="controller.enableListPrice()" ng-model="controller.data.ListPrice" value="{{controller.data.ListPrice|currency}}"/>

However it allows me to type only one number with the currency format.

For instance if I type 123, I see 1.00$, 2.00$, 3.00 $ flicker.

If I type 123 I need to see: 123$.

Any Suggestions and ideas.
```

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing the value of the input each time.  When you set the value of the input, it changes the text in the input field, and when you keep typing you overwrite it again.  You can show the input in a separate span like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="controller.enableListPrice()" ng-model="controller.data.ListPrice">
<span> {{controller.data.ListPrice|currency}}</span>
```

If you really want to show the currency value in the input, you can much around with some JS/CSS to show the span in front of the input and hide the actual input value underneath.

Comment: Thanks so much. I want to show currency in the input. How do I that.

Comment: Plenty of ways to do it, but here's a suggestion for writing a custom directive that makes sense to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576202/angular-input-field-with-a-currency-mask-directive-for-money-format-on-the-fly