# angularjs input type="number" not displaying negative numbers with a decimal fraction

Tags: html, angularjs

When trying to enter a negative number with a decimal fraction into an input field of type number bound to a value with angularjs, the value is converted to NaN when the decimal character is a comma (as is standard in my country). The code is pretty simple:

```
<form>
      <input type="number" ng-model="positiveMoney" />
      {{positiveMoney}}
      </br>
      <input type="number" ng-model="negativeMoney" />
      {{negativeMoney}}
</form>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.positiveMoney = 99.89;
  $scope.negativeMoney = -99.89;
});
```

I have set up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6sbDm9fqoIWVHUHyoSAi?p=preview)

to demonstrate this behaviour. When first running the plunker, the values are displayed correctly (and with a comma as a separator), but when deleting the minus sign and reentering it, the value isn't a number any more. I am using angularjs v1.2 and google chrome as my browser. When on the other hand I replace the comma with a decimal point, the value is displayed correctly, but this isn't the standard locale in my country (Croatia).

**Edit:**

Solved this eventually (with the help of Maxim Shoustin's suggestion) in a pragmatic way like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c6AYbSPxLsX0t4X5L2Ng?p=preview):

```
app.directive('money', ['$filter',
  function($filter) {

    var MONEY_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d{1,2})?$/;
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
          if (MONEY_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('float', true);
            if (typeof viewValue === "money")
              return viewValue;
            else
              return parseFloat(viewValue.replace(',', '.'));
          } else {
            ctrl.$setValidity('money', false);
            return undefined;
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

The directive accepts both commas and dots as the decimal separator. Also only two digits are allowed after the decimal point.

Comment: I answered once on something similar, might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576202/angular-input-field-with-a-currency-mask-directive-for-money-format-on-the-fly/19576763#19576763

Comment: Anyways comma separated shows 10^3 partition like in Excel and other apps. I think you need write custom directive to make this change because demo you posted you use native way of type=number

Comment: I guess you're right. It's a pitty because type="number" did the text to number conversion automatically. If it's text I have to implement the number conversions myself.

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin. Your suggestion help me solve my problem. If you formulate your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the correct answer.