# formatting on ng-model for the display but keeping the value as a float in controller

Tags: angularjs

```
Amount : <input type="text" ng-model="amount" />
```

Within controller:

```
amount=1000.00
```

Is there a way where I could display the value in the textbox as

```
Amount : 1,000.00
```

and still keep the value in controller as currency/number so that i dont have to parse them into float whenever i need to do some operations.

Comment: You need to create custom directive that extends `ng-model` then add custom parser and formatter, there is plenty of tutorials how to do that e.g. https://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html If you just starting with AngualJS it will be better to google some free to use component...

Comment: PS. Here is good and easy to grasp sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576202/angular-input-field-with-a-currency-mask-directive-for-money-format-on-the-fly

Comment: Here is an example of someone solving this exact problem: http://blog.yodersolutions.com/add-comma-separated-thousands-to-number-input-in-angularjs/

Comment: There are a number of input mask directives available for angular. Here are 3: https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks, https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask and http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/ if you go with any of them I'd love to hear back on how they worked.

Answer (score 1):

use it in the view like this for amount formatting.

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="amount.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', minimumFractionDigits: 2})"/>
```